# Was it ever shown or explained how intelligent underwater species in the Star Wars galaxy developed technology?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, science

There are a huge bunch of species that originated underwater in the *Star Wars* galaxy. My question was: How did they become technologically advanced if they couldn't invent fire? I did some digging and learned that the most famous aquatic *Star Wars* species, the [Mon Calamari](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Mon_Calamari), were surface dwellers in their prehistory and they eventually shared their tech with the solely underwater [Quarren](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Quarren). That's fine, but have we ever seen or heard how a solely underwater-based civilization developed to be space-faring in Legends or Canon?

Comment: This is a galaxy where cross-contamination of technology has been happening for millions of years.

Comment: Yes but many species evolved in utter isolation.

Comment: Here on Earth, electric eels can certainly do things with electricity, without needing fire to extract metals.  A biological approach to technology seems plausible enough.

Comment: That kind of storytelling doesn't really happen in Star Wars. It's a fantasy/fairy tale setting, not hard sci-fi.

Answer (score -1):

One possible way that a species of aquatic intelligent beings could acquire technology is mentioned in Larry Niven's story "Handicap" (1967).

https://archive.org/details/Galaxy_v26n02_1967-12_modified/page/n79/mode/2up?view=theater

Comment: Handicap is not set in the Star Wars universe.

Comment: Link-only answers are also pretty useless.